# Appending row to empty DataFrame converts dtype from int to object

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to add a series consisting of ints to a dataframe, but the items in the dataframe get converted to objects, instead of ints.

How can I keep the dtype as int for the items in the dataframe.

Here is some demo code:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns =['a','b','c'],  dtype=int)
>>> row = pd.Series(0,['a','b','c'],dtype=int)
>>> row = row.rename('row')
>>> print(row)
a    0
b    0
c    0
Name: row, dtype: int64
>>> df.append(row)['a']
row    0
Name: a, dtype: object
>>>
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I get different `dtype`s: `row` is `int32` (you had `int64`), df is `float64` and it prints `row  0.0` on the last line. pandas `0.23.3`, python `3.6.6`, numpy `1.15.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dtype=int` apparently doesn't stick when you initiate the dataframe with no data.

#### Workround

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c']).astype(int)
row = pd.Series(0, ['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=int, name='row')

df.append(row).dtypes

a    int64
b    int64
c    int64
dtype: object
```